# Create signup with Swift in Xcode 6 using Parse as backend

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, ios8, xcode6

I'm trying to create a user sign-up form on Xcode with Parse as the backend, referring to a number of related tutorials, of which nearly all use Objective-C.
 **The question:** Where am I going wrong with the following code? Besides [Parse.setApplicationId("", clientKey: "")], do I need another piece in the vein of the test code in AppDelegate to connect everything? If so, what could this be? I've tried various permutations and I just can't seem to push the data to the established user table.

```
//  SignupViewController.swift

import UIKit

class SignupViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var messageLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
@IBAction func signupAction(sender: UIButton) {

    var emlEntered = emailTextField.text
    var pwdEntered = passwordTextField.text

        var user = PFUser()
        user.email = self.emailTextField.text
        user.password = self.passwordTextField.text

        user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
            } else {
                self.messageLabel.text = "All fields are required."
            }
        }
    }  
}
}
```

Thanks in advance as I'm completely new to Swift, iOS development, and Parse.

Comment: what is the problem exactly?

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. So Parse is not picking up any "user" input in its database, which tells me that the code is not passing any data back. I don't know why this is the case.

Comment: when signUpInBackgroundWithBlock retunrs, is there any error? And if so, can you print it out?

Comment: The code runs without any errors.

Comment: I'm sorry, what I added as an answer, that wanted to be a comment. So there is no error, but did the program entered the // Hooray! Let them use the app now. section? You can write a println() to there to find out if that part of the code is reached, or the block is not even executed.

Comment: No prob at all. Just appreciate the feedback. I'll look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what the actual question is but you have to send the data you entered to parse.

```
var user = PFUser()
            user.username = self.usernameTextField.text
            user.email = self.emailTextField.text
            user.password = self.passwordTextField.text

            user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in
```

in Appdelegate the code has to look like

```
Parse.setApplicationId("appId", clientKey: "clientKey")
```

Comment: Thanks, Denai. I've edited for clarity; hopefully, my question is more clear. Thanks too for sharing the code above. I've tried it in lieu of one portion of the code, but it didn't solve the problem. I'm sure you are right though; I might be missing one particular piece in AppDelegate to connect things. From everything I've read and watched, it seems that all I needed in AppDelegate was the app key and client ID in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, while the code to push data to Parse would be in the view controller. I have nothing after the app key and client ID in the AppDelegate as a result.

Comment: Do your Appdelegate look like I edited below? and do you set the right Bundle identifier? You dont need more stuff to connect your app to parse.

Comment: Thanks, Denai. My AppDelegate does look the code showed above.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of further trial-and-error, I figured out what went awry, or really what was excluded and therefore had gone awry. I added "UITextDelegate" as type alongside "UIViewController", which was that one piece needed to tie everything together -- at least for my app. Hope this can help anyone who's just starting out. 
Thanks much to Daniel and Denai for taking time to inquire and post suggestions!